# Web Scraping API - "See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets."

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website, https://www.huntr.co/jobs and it has about 1 million listing. I checked and found that the website is ajax loaded so decided to scrape the website using its API which is, https://app.huntr.co/public/search/job-posts?page=1. The website has data loaded in json format and when I change "page= " I get a new page with new data. But whenever I cross "page = 332", the API gives the following message in json:

```
{"message":"[query_phase_execution_exception] Result window is too large, from + size must be less 
than or equal to: [10000] but was [30030]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request 
large data sets. This limit can be set by changing the [index.max_result_window] index level 
setting.","error":{"status":500}
```

I dont understand what a scroll api is and how can I request that. Due to this error I am able to scrape about only 10,000 listing out of 1 million listing. I am using python for this project. Any solution will be highly appreciated !

Comment: I'm getting results for `332`

Comment: There no results after 332, try 333 or 335 !

Comment: It's a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086701/web-scraping-a-job-platform-with-1-million-listings

Answer (score 0):

The website uses infinite scrolling mechanism in order to get data i.e as and when you scroll down the page, a ajax call will be sent with the next page number.

As you don't know the number of pages before hand, you can rough calculate the number of pages if you know total results and the number of results per page.

Then you can try out manually in a similar binary search manner where is the last page.

So, the last page is `332`. Page `333` gives error response

Comment: Total results is about 1 million and number of result is 30. So doing the calculation, no. of page = 1 000 000 / 30 = 33 333. But  <https://app.huntr.co/public/search/job-posts?page=33333> gives the same  result as before unfortunately !

Comment: @mustaqSHAH Google also gives so many searches paginated but it also knows no human can go beyond a certain page. Hence, though while showing they say so many results, but internally they would have calculated results upto certain pages only